# MySQL One Master Multiple Slave Configuration

Tags: mysql

I have 3 servers (suppose A[Master], B[Slave], C[Slave]). Server A has 2 databases which are replicated to B. Now i want to create one more database in A which will be replicated to C.  Here only the new database will be replicated to C. Is this possible? If yes how? I am using MySQL Enterprise edition 5.7.16.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you miss understand the concept of Master to Slave relationship. Slaves should always be 100% reflation on master in case master goes down and system will need to appoint a new master.

Comment: @NashPL I had the same requirement from the client so.

Comment: I see. I would go back to client to renegotiate it.